# How to Remove these small box(edge) structure from face in blender?

Tags: faces, edges, subdivision-surface

I want to remove this small box structure from the face and want the face as sown in second image

[image]

[image]

Comment: on the left menu of your 3D view (activated with T) > Tool Tag > Shading > Smooth. Also I think you have to recalculate your Normals: enter in Edit mode, select all, and ctrl N.

Answer (score 1):

On the left menu of your 3D view (activated with <kbd>T</kbd>) click Tools tab > *Shading* panel > Faces > Smooth. Also I think you have to recalculate your normals: enter  Edit mode, select all, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>